# strcspn() stopping at a period

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm writing a function that should parse a string containing a description of a dice roll, for instance "2*1d8+2". I extract the four values OK when they are integers, but I want to be able to use floats as well for the multiplier and the addition at the end. Things get nasty when I try to parse such a string: "1.8*1d8+2.5".

I have determined that the problem is with the function `strcspn`. I ask it to parse the input string `s` (which contains the dice string) and stop at either an asterisk or an 'x':

```
const char * s = "1.8*1d8+2.5";
size_t l = strcspn(s,"*x");
```

The function should return `3`, as the asterisk is at the 4th position. However, it seems to stop on the decimal separator (period) and returns `1`.

It's not that I can't continue writing my function without this, as there are other ways to get things done, but still I'm curious why such a thing would happen. Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

[EDIT]

Nevermind, I've found the answer, and it was my stupidity rather than the compiler playing tricks on me. I used this code:

```
if (l = strcspn(s,"*x") < strlen(s)) {
...
```

which returned `1` (or `true`) because `strcspn(s,"*x") < strlen(s)` evaluates to `true` - and was assigned to the `l` variable. I should have added parentheses:

```
if ((l = strcspn(s,"*x")) < strlen(s)) {
...
```

Thanks for your answers nonetheless, particularly @sleske, who made me analyse my code more deeply (which led to finding the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an error somewhere else. I wrote a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main(){
  const char * s = "1.8*1d8+2.5";
  size_t l = strcspn(s,"*x");
  printf("l: %d\n", l);
}
```

and compiled it with `gcc` on Linux. On my system, it outputs "3".

Please post a complete, working example that exhibits the problem. Then we'll see...

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just as you posted it for me<sup>1</sup>.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  const char * s = "1.8*1d8+2.5";
  size_t l = strcspn(s,"*x");
  printf("%zd (%.*s)\n", l, (int)l, s);
  return 0;
}
so ross$ ./a.out
3 (1.8)
```

---

<sup>1. Mac OS X 10.6.4</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `sscanf` instead of manually finding stop points and parsing myself. You can get your integers and floats easily out of the string with that.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm not looking for an alternative solution, because there are multiple options available. I'm just wondering why `strcspn` would stop on the period instead of either `*` or `x`.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char * s = "1.8*1d8+2.5";
    size_t l = strcspn(s,"*x");
    printf("<<%s>> %zd <<%s>>\n", s, l, s+l);
    return 0;
}
```

produces this answer on MacOS 10.6.4 (GCC 4.5.1):

```
<<1.8*1d8+2.5>> 3 <<*1d8+2.5>>
```

If your compiler and library does not produce the same answer, get a fixed/upgraded version of the software.

(NB: The 'z' modifier in the `printf()` format string is a C99 feature - it indicates that the type of the parameter is `size_t`.)